# 1 laptop + 1 pc need to share 4 dvi lcds (is this possible?)

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi

I am in need of a kvm that i can use with a laptop and a pc.

Is this possible?

Currently i am using a very old iogear usb kvm for keyboard and mouse.  I want to make all 4 monitors available to both pc's.  I have also been using maxi vista software solution however it does not have work with software that is hardware accelerated which is becoming much more prevalent (i.e. most browers, office 2013 etc. use hw acceleration)  Maxi Vista is phasing out as a solution for me.

The pc has a dual head video card.  The laptop has a vga, display port and hdmi port for video.

Any ideas?

i.e. i can plug all 4 lcd's into a kvm however how will they be available to each pc?

Answer (score 0):

There is hardware that makes possible to switch between input sources (PC or laptop).
It has switch, that on the LCD you can see first or second computer. Switching mouse or keyboard is also possible.

Also there is software like Synergy that extends the desktop or makes it available on other computer like it would be connected to the computer that runs it. It depends on Ethernet/LAN connection.

Comment: I was looking at http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815106011 triplehead2go but not sure if it will work with a kvm (so that i can have 2 pc's take advantage of the lcd's)

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but this is strictly hardware, so software shouldn't matter. Ask the seller for compatibility or borrow one for short period of time to try it first.

Comment: The answer from matrox was no.  It is not approved to work with any kvm products. (it may, they just are saying that it is not supported)